# Why Windows Server 2019 network adapter sets to public after reboot?

Tags: windows, networking, reboot, adapter, public

After restarts it set to "Network 2" instead of "domain.local".
I have to disable the adapter, and re-enable to get back the "domain.local"

Why is it happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your post with ipconfig infotmation. First things to check are DNS servers and DNS suffix set on your NIC

Comment: We checked the DNS and its set to static....if the host has fix ip set, can we change it to dynamic?

Comment: This is a common problem and I don't have a solution, but you can restart the NLA service to fix it rather than disabling and enabling the network adapter.